# How to import Kaggle dataset to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have been training my dataset ( 6 GO of images ) in Google Colab lately, but i found that the RAM isn't sufficient, i moved to Google Cloud platform ( Free year trial 300$ ) but i found that thing are very complicated there than google Colab  . 
Is there any way to import Kaggle dataset to Google cloud platform directly using Kaggle API ?
If not , can i upload my 6 G0 dataset from Google drive to Google Cloud Platform ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [official](https://www.kaggle.com/c/passenger-screening-algorithm-challenge/discussion/37088) port from Kaggle, according to this, using the command line from google this is possible:

```
$ gsutil mb -c regional -l us-east1 gs://my-kaggle-data
$ gsutil -m cp -r gs://kaggle-tsa-stage1/*  gs://my-kaggle-data
$ gsutil ls gs://my-kaggle-data
```

Did you try to follow that guide? There are also videos showing how to do this, for example [this one](https://youtu.be/wo--uiuPsiU)